# How to implement listView item with longPress event

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need a ListView with long pressed event handler.
When listviewItem is longpressed, an popup should appear for example.

Does anyone knows, if this is possible with xamarin.forms MVVM?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue about this in xamarin forms, you can check it here: [[Enhancement] LongPressGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3480).

And just as this remark mentioned :

> this will probably be in .NET MAUI but won't make it into
> Xamarin.Forms anymore. If needed check out the Xamarin Community
> Toolkit or other relevant libraries

But there are several workarounds:

You can refer to article: [Longpress Event For Image In Xamarin.Forms](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/longpress-event-for-image/).

And you can also check thread : [How to make long press gesture in Xamarin Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569515/how-to-make-long-press-gesture-in-xamarin-forms)